# Error switching from grunt compass to libsass

Tags: gruntjs, compass, libsass

I am working on moving over from grunt-contrib-compass to grunt-sass. I am seeing that the libsass compiler is failing on some of the imports in the main.scss file, though.

Here is main.scss

```
@import "breakpoint";
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/css3/user-interface";
@import "compass/css3/transform";
@import "compass/utilities/general/clearfix";
```

And here is the error thrown when running the sass task:

```
file to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint
Current dir: example/styles/
Line 1  Column 9  example/styles/main.scss
```

Does anybody familiar with making the switch to libsass from compass know if there are equivalents for these imports that I could drop in as replacements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the import path for `breakpoint` to point to where the `_breakpoint.scss` is located.

grunt-contrib-compass has an `importPath` option (e.g. `importPath: '/bower_components'`,) which

> Makes files under the specified folder findable by Sass's @import
>   directive

Since that was removed from your gruntfile, you should now use the full path to import it:

```
@import "/bower_components/breakpoint/breakpoint";
```

**Edit**: libsass has a similar option 'loadPath' which takes an array of paths to search for files to @import.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  libsass: {
    options: {
      loadPath: ['my/load/path']
    },
    files: {[
        {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'my/src/dir',
            src: ['**/*.scss'],
            dest: 'dist',
            ext: '.css'
        }
    ]},
  }});
```

Your new config for libsass will include

If you choose not to do that, you'll need to install breakpoint globally just like you did for compass.

```
gem "breakpoint", "~>2.4.0"
```

Comment: Thanks @Rachid. I guess that is the question. Are there ways to install, for libsass, imports that are equivalent to the ones we have been using for compass? And how would that work? Your example of `gem "breakpoint", "~>2.4.0"` doesn't make sense, to me, since this is libsass land, not ruby land. Or am I missing something?

Comment: libsass has an option `loadPath` which take an array of paths to search for files to @import. (I'll update the answer to include that).

As for `gem`, you were already using `compass` which means you had ruby already installed. using gem to install `breakpoint` will jsut make it available globally to all ur project just like `compass`.

Comment: Yeah, as part of this work, I am seeking to remove the dependency on gems altogether. I should have made that clear earlier. Thanks!